# Calling awakeFromNib from xib file in the main ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib, custom-cell, awakefromnib

I have a custom cell in a `UITableView` using an xib file. I programatically created a `UILabel` with a height of 200 and a width of 50. When I do an `NSLog` in the `customCell.m` of the label's width and height, it gives me w: 50 and h: 200. But when I do an `NSLog` in `mainViewController.m` it gives me 0 for the height and width.

Not sure why it does that. I need to get the real height of the label in the `mainViewController.m`

Here's my code:

`customCell.m`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.label];

    NSLog(@"%f", self.label.frame.size.height);  // Results: 200.0000
}
```

`mainViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    customCell *cellVC = [[cutsomCell alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", cellVC.label.frame.size.height); // Results: 0.0000
}
```

Isn't `awakeFromNib` supposed to get called the `mainViewController.m` at `viewDidLoad` if I use an xib file? If not, how do I call it in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is an initializer called when you load from nib..ie you add a view and change its class to your custom class in storyboard/nib and this porcess will call `awakeFromNib` method..not programatically

When done programatically use init method for the purpose or a custom initializer

```
-(id)init
{
    //class super init calls

    //then method calls
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.label];

    //return self
}
```

**Example**

```
- (id) init {
    // Call superclass's initializer
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
        [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];
        [self.myView addSubview:self.label];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what that means... I'm a beginner. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: This solved the problem of my question, but now, I don't see the label